# MSTest v2 Ordered Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and MSTest V2. My solution has multiple Unit Test projects. In one project, I have unit tests that are testing the loading of resources from the installation directory. Most test that the resources are loaded correctly, but some delete the resource to confirm that this is handled correctly as well.

[image]

The issue that I am having is that the tests run in parallel. Therefore, the tests that remove the resources do this at the same time the tests that are loading the resources are running, and I get failed tests.

I realize I can resolve this by updating my code to send the directory to search, or by running one set of tests and then the next, but I would prefer being able to run all tests at once. It sounds like MSTest v2 is supposed to run sequentially unless otherwise directed to run in parallel, but on my system, this is demonstrably false. It also appears that Ordered Test does not work with v2. Is there a way to get MSTest V2 to run sequentially?

Comment: I am having the same issue with MSTest and was wondering whether you were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @user1207289 - I was not able to get it to run sequentially. I switched to nUnit for my next project. For this one that already had tests, I used locked on an object to force sequential processing on the methods where it was required. Not the best way to go, but it was the only solution that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

1. MStest v2 will not support orderedtests
   [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/25)
2. you may have set the parallelization scope in testsettings file or Assembly file
   https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-execute-tests-in-parallel.htm
   If you remove that it will run sequentially

I would say that you can create a flag and update that from dependent test, check for the flag status before cleaning up resource. may be a dictionary of testname and status, once its done, execute this test or wait for that test to complete. you can implement a custom logic for that.

Answer (score -1):

To make the tests run sequentially, set MaxCpuCount to 1 in your .runsettings file, for more information see: [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately this did not work. According to the documentation, "The test execution engine starts as a distinct process on each available core, and gives each core a container with tests to run." These tests still seem to be run in parallel, but are restricted to a single core.

Comment: According to the linked docs, the default value is 1. So this is not true assuming the user does not already have a .runsettings file.